# iPhone Development - multiple views in one window.

Tags: iphone, view

I want to have a UIView at the top half of my app, and a UITable at the bottom half. If I create a basic window application I can do this using IB. My main problem is that I seem to be only to do this in the delegate file which I would like to avoid.

I repeat the exact same steps I did in delegate in a separate controller and all I get is a blank screen.

```
0@interface RootViewController : UIWindow {
    UIWindow *myWindow;
    UIView *headerView;
    UITableView *tableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *headerView; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *myWindow; 

@end
```

I have each of these connect to the right view in rootviewcontroller.xib

I was wondering if anyone had any advice / snippets / examples I could use?

Comment: Looks like you don't really know what's going on. Interface Builder helps you build interfaces and string them up with your code. You can't do anything just with IB itself. I suggest you step back a bit and actually learn Objective-C / Cocoa with books and documentation.

Comment: it isn't even that, I have made something before with each view having it's own unique controller, my issue here is, I don't know how to have one controller manage two views without doing it programatically, hence asking to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both the delegate file and Interface Builder.  Interface Builder makes a view that binds to your delegate through IBOutlets and IBActions.  I would run through several iPhone tutorials found on google before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Your RootViewController certainly shouldn't be a subclass of UIWindow.  You probably want UIViewController for that.